# Local min and max difference in Numpy python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy, filter

I am trying to write a function that calculates the maximum dip in the numpy arrays `A, B, C, D` and get the Expected Result. For array `C` it the values `0,10,-110,23,` shows that from 0 it went to 11 and went back down to -110 resulting in a total drawdown of `-120`. How would I be able to calculate such a thing?

```
import numpy as np

def MXincrementedDrawdown(cumsum):
    prev = np.arange(0, len(cumsum)-1)
    current =np.arange(1, len(cumsum))
    if cumsum[prev] > cumsum[current]:
        difference = cumsum[prev] - cumsum[current]
        print(difference)
    else: 
        return 'No drawdown'
    print("Maximum Drawdown of Incremented is {}".format(difference))

A = np.array([0,2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
B = np.array([0,10,-110,23,45,66,30,2,12])
C = np.array([0,10,11,-23,45,11,66,45,4,12])
D = np.array([0,5,6,7,8])

MXincrementedDrawdown(A)
MXincrementedDrawdown(B)
MXincrementedDrawdown(C)
MXincrementedDrawdown(D)
```

Expected Output:

```
-56
-120
-62
No drawdown
```

Comment: It is not clear how you calculate the output. First, limit yourself only to one array (let's say, C). Why do you start at 66 and disregard the previous six elements? Surely -23 is smaller than 4. Are you looking at the difference between the smallest item _after_ the largest item?

Comment: Sorry had to update the issue, I am just trying to see how far the downward trend has lasted for. Calculate how much it has decreased from the highest point before the fall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the question right

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
_min  = min(a)
index_min = np.where(a == _min)[0][0] #first occurence
_max = max(a[:index_min])
print(_min-_max)
```

Comment: thanks for trying out my issue but im afraid the outputs do not match with the expected Outputs of my issue, with the following results for arrays `A,B,C,D` :  `-44,-176,-89,-8` .  Instead of `-56,-120,-62,No drawdown`

Comment: @tonyselcuk Fixed it. I did the reverse of what I intended to do.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but everything works except for the C array.

Comment: How are you getting -62? The smallest number is -23 and the largest number before it is 11. -23-11=-34. Or am I missing somepart of the integral logic?

Comment: Never mind its all good thanks for the help, sorry for the trouble.