# Calculating the drawdown within a Numpy Array Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, numpy, indexing

I am trying to write a function that calculates how much the biggest dip was in each array. the function below calculates between the max and the min but it does not get Expected Output I am looking for. The resultant of `calc(C)` should be -62 since `11,66,45,4` the value went down from 66 to 4 in the array resulting in the dip to be -62 points below 66. How would I be able to fix the function below? Sample code gotten from: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061903/local-min-and-max-difference-in-numpy-python)

```
def calc(arr):
    try:
        _min  = min(arr)
        index_min = np.where(arr == _min)[0][0] #first occurence
        _max = max(arr[:index_min])
        print(_min-_max)
    except:
        print('No drawdown')

A = np.array([0,2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
B = np.array([0,10,-110,23,45,66,30,2,12])
C = np.array([0,10,11,-23,45,11,66,45,4,12])
D = np.array([0,5,6,7,8])
E = np.array([0,10,5,6,8])

calc(A)
calc(B)
calc(C)
calc(D)
calc(E)
```

Output:

```
-56
-120
-34
No drawdown
No drawdown
```

Expected Output:

```
-56
-120
-62
No drawdown
-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest dip does not necessarily happen at the global maximum or global minimum. We need an exhaustive approach to find the largest dip:

1. check the maximum value so far, for which we can use `numpy.maximum.accumulate`;
2. calculate the biggest dip for each position.
3. And take the largest dip among all the dips.

---

```
def calc(a):
    acc_max = np.maximum.accumulate(a)
    return (a - acc_max).min()

calc(A)
# -56
calc(B)
# -120
calc(C)
# -62
calc(D)
# 0
calc(E)
# -5
```

Comment: Thank you it works, is it also possible to see between from what value to what value it dips from something like `Array C: from 66 to 4 , Indexes: 6 - 8`

Comment: You can find the dip index with `dip_idx = (a - acc_max).argmin()` and then find the peak index with `a[:dip_idx].argmax()`.

Comment: how would I be able to do the opposite and get the maximum upside instead of the maximum drawdown. I made a post in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230032/getting-the-maximum-upside-between-numpy-arrays-python  . I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it