# Getting the maximum upswing in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, indexing

I am trying to write a function that calculates how much the biggest upside was in each array. The function below calculates between the max and the min but it does not get Expected Output I am looking for. The resultant of `calc(C)` should be 89 since `11, -23, 45, 11, 66` the value went up from `-23 to 66` in the array resulting in the upside to be 89 points. How would I be able to fix the function below? Sample code gotten from: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106694/calculating-the-drawdown-within-a-numpy-array-python)

```
def calc(arr):
    try:
        acc_max = np.minimum.accumulate(arr)
        result = (arr + acc_max).min()
        dip_idx = (arr + acc_max).argmin()
        max_idx= arr[:dip_idx].argmax()
        print("Result: {} Between Values: {},{} Indexes: {},{}".format(result, arr[max_idx],arr[dip_idx],max_idx,dip_idx))
        return result
    except:
        print("No Upside")

A = np.array([2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
B = np.array([10,-110,23,45,66,30,2,12])
C = np.array([10,11,-23,45,11,66,45,4,12])
D = np.array([8,7,6,5])
E = np.array([10,5,6,8])

calc(A)
calc(B)
calc(C)
calc(D)
calc(E)
```

Output

```
A Result: -24 Between Values: 44,-12 Indexes: 2,3
B Result: -220 Between Values: 10,-110 Indexes: 0,1
C Result: -46 Between Values: 11,-23 Indexes: 1,2
C No Upside
E Result: 10 Between Values: 10,5 Indexes: 0,3
```

Expected output:

```
A Result: 42 Between Values: 2,44 Indexes: 0,2
B Result: 176 Between Values: -110,66 Indexes: 1,4
C Result: 89 Between Values: -23,66 Indexes: 2,5
C No Upside
E Result: 3 Between Values: 5,8 Indexes: 1,3
```

Comment: Also, your code never raises an error. Besides the typo, neither `C` or `D` triggers the output "no upside"

Comment: I am unable to reproduce either of your last two outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work, however I do suggest some better names for the variables (see below), I kept yours to show the difference.

```
def calc(arr):
    try:
        acc_max = np.minimum.accumulate(arr)
        result = (arr - acc_max).max()
        dip_idx = (arr - acc_max).argmax()
        max_idx= arr[:dip_idx].argmin()
        print("Result: {} Between Values: {},{} Indexes: {},{}".format(result, arr[max_idx],arr[dip_idx],max_idx,dip_idx))
        return result
    except:
        print("No Upside")
```

I changed `arr + acc_max` to `arr - acc_max` as well as `arr[:dip_idx].argmin()` to `arr[:dip_idx].argmax()`

**Explanation:**
`acc_max` will be the lowest number found so far in the array. So, what you want to do is subtract this array form the original array, to get the diff between each element and the minimum number found so far in the array, i.e. `arr - acc_max` will contain all these diffs.

Then `(arr - acc_max).max()` will give you the maximum diff (which you are looking for), i.e. the maximum gain. So, `result` will hold the value for the maximum gain, while `dip_idx` will hold the index for the value where the maximum gain was achieved.

`max_idx= arr[:dip_idx].argmin()` will then find the minimum value for the array, *before* the max-gain-value was achieved, i.e. this will be the index for the "start" of the gain.

So, with some better naming for the variables:

```
def calc(arr):
    try:
        min_so_far = np.minimum.accumulate(arr)
        max_gain = (arr - min_so_far).max()
        max_gain_end_idx = (arr - min_so_far).argmax()
        max_gain_start_idx= arr[:max_gain_end_idx].argmin()
        print("Result: {} Between Values: {},{} Indexes: {},{}".format(          max_gain,arr[max_gain_end_idx],arr[max_gain_start_idx],max_gain_start_idx,max_gain_end_idx)
         )
        return max_gain
    except:
        print("No Upside")
```

Comment: You don't actually catch the case of a monotonically decreasing array. None of this code raises an error. Also, your indentation is not correct.

Comment: Monotonically decreasing array? Can you give me an example, I'm not sure i follow (do you mean like `[10,9,8,7,6]`? That I do think I catch...

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: My code gives `No Upside` for that array, what would you consider to be the correct output then?

Comment: Yup. You fixed it

Comment: Fixed it? When? I haven't change the code in my reply (you can look through the change-history yourself).

Comment: My mistake. I meant you fixed OP's code, which definitely was not correct

Comment: Ahh, then I follow :)

Comment: I totaly agree, it should be handeled more gracefully (like your answer). I was trying to aim for "change as little as possible while fixing the issue" kind of answer.

Comment: I just wanted to rant at OP for posting a sloppy question, even if it was relatively interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of what happens when you copy and paste a bunch of code without attempting to understand it. The first tip-off is

```
acc_max = np.minimum.accumulate(arr)
```

Why is the running minimum called `acc_max`? Another thing is that your code can not throw an error anywhere, which you would have noticed if you pasted a proper MCVE.

The correct answer is that you want to accumulate the running minimum, subtract it off the array, and find the maximum of the result. You don't have a result when the entire array is monotonically decreasing, which will lead to `np.minimum.accumulate` returning `arr`, and the difference being exactly zero everywhere.

```
def calc(arr):
    running_min = np.minimum.accumulate(arr)
    delta = arr - running_min
    if not delta.any():
        print('No upswing')
        return None
    max_idx = delta.argmax()
    result = delta[max_idx]
    min_idx = arr[:max_idx].argmin()
    print(f'Result: {result} Between values {arr[min_idx]}, {arr[max_idx]} at indices {min_idx}, {max_idx}')
    return result
```

This produces the expected results for all your test inputs.